# Black screens using xrandr for multiple displays with HiDPI in Linux Mint

Tags: nvidia, xrandr

My setup uses 3 Monitors in Linux Mint.
Left is a TV, using 1080p, connected via HDMI-0, centered a 4k monitor via DP-1 and the right one is again a 1080p monitor via DVI-D-0.

```
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --scale 1.5x1.5 --auto --fb 9600x2160 --pos 0x0 
--output DP-1 --auto --fb 9600x2160 --pos 2880x0 
--output DVI-D-0 --scale 1.5x1.5 --auto --fb 9600x2160 --pos 6720x0
```

works fine, however I need the scaling to be 2 for some applications.

I used

```
xrandr --output HDMI-0 --scale 2x2 --auto --fb 11520x2160 --pos 0x0 
--output DP-1 --auto --fb 11520x2160 --pos 3840x0 
--output DVI-D-0 --scale 2x2 --auto --fb 11520x2160 --pos 7680x0
```

which would be, what I need.
The problem is, the TV and the 1080p monitor on the right become black, sometimes flickering at the very top.

A scaling of even 3 works perfectly as well.

Is there an alternativ way, I can configure it or can I do something else with xrandr?

I am using Linux Mint 17.2 Cinnamon 64-bit Rafaela, have an Nvidia Card, Nvidia X Server Settings are available, but don't support the scaling.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. It seems to be working up to scale 1.71x1.71. Everything bigger causes smaller display to go blank